# How I can add a "quick add" button in dropdown of grocery crud?

Tags: codeigniter, crud, grocery-crud

I have two tables Categories and Products
I have made a simple relation between them so I can quickly choose from a dropdown of Categories
My question: is there a way to put an 'add new' in that dropdown? 
so the user won't have to go out to the category edit section to add a category

Comment: Some code examples might be useful with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/)

Here is client side example

HTML

```
<select id="my-items" multiple>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$('#my-items').selectize({
    create: function(input) {
        //This function will create the category on the server side
        if(create_new_category(input)){
            return {
                value: input,
                text: input
           }
        }

        return false;

    }
});

function create_new_category(input){
    alert('Category '+input+' created on server');

    return true; //if created successfully otherwise return false
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x60rqvzs/).

Example is with multiple select, if don`t need multiple just remove the attribute.
Also you will have to provide an ajax controller for creating new category.

If you are using Grocery Crud, 
you need to overwrite the column if you want this in list view.
[Example](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/callback_column)

Or to overwrite the edit field if you want it in edit view.
[Example](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/callback_edit_field)

Comment: Just check Selectize.js, a question is there a way that the "option just added" stays in the dropdown??? after refresh, I tried and example and whenever I refreshed the form, my new option disappeared